# Following is an excerpt from a power electronics textbook. Is the statement true?

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, switch-mode-power-supply, dielectric, esr

[image]

As far as I know ESR primarily depends on the type of dielectric.
eg: Al electrolytic (higher capacitance value) would have much higher ESR than ceramic (usually lower capacitance value).

Say for identical dielectric type, do we have an inverse relation between capacitance and ESR?

Comment: As a general statement, this is very misleading since ESR depends on the construction of the capcitor. If you look at the same series of capacitors from a manufacturer, the larger capacitance capacitors will have lower ESR than the smaller valued ones at a given voltage.

Comment: The statement is certainly a simplification and the assumption is probably a constant dissipation factor of the capacitors.

Comment: So which textbook is that taken from?

Comment: So was that a cheap copy of what was a good textbook?

Comment: Any questions on my answer, it could be simplified or expanded into a chapter

Answer (score 3):

> for identical dielectric type, do we have an inverse relation between capacitance and ESR?

Yes ESR is due to the dielectric-conductor interface and the surface roughness to increase effective area and the resistance of the conductor itself. This can be a sintered powder, acid etched or other means to reduce ESR in the electrode interface.

**So ESR is an AC resistance and rises towards DC.**

An increase in  electrode area automatically increases C and reduces the interface ESR resistance.  You might think an increase the height of a cylinder  adds resistance but just the opposite as the electrodes wrap in the radial direction and this also lowers ESR.

This is always true within the same volume, height, voltage rating, dielectric type and conductive electrode type.  It can gradually change in frequency as the parasitic inductive DCR of the electrodes negates and electrode interface  ESR somewhat.

Gap between electrodes may be reduced to achieve the same capacitance, then the voltage rating is reduced.  Length of the electrode multi-layer or coil may be increased which increases C while reducing ESR.  Metalfilm conductor electrodes have one of the lowest ESR values due to the highest ratio of effective surface contact area over the average area.

The Rule of thumb is to compare the \$C.\text{ESR}=T\$ values within a family of types and all types to achieve the best balance of low ESR over the broadest frequency range. This is why the old habit of using C values decades apart in C value were used in parallel as the SRF values shifted and ESR vs f only covered up to this series self resonant frequency.

For e-Caps in the 1 to 500 \$\mu F\$ range or so, \$C.\text{ESR} =< 20 \mu \text{s} \$ for low ESR and general purpose e-caps are 10x worse or lower frequency or longer  \$ T= C.\text{ESR}\$. Much Larger e-caps will have \$T\$ time constants in the milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

That statement is true within a capacitor family.  It's not necessarily true when you compare different capacitor chemistry types.  After all, ESR is a chemistry and construction effect.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is true if the construction principle and the materials are same in all capacitors included to comparison. But for me this statement is useless. I need a certain capacitance for my circuit construction. And I need small enough ESR just for this capacitance. That forces me to compare different capacitor types which all have the same capacitance.